# How can I add Documents in "Personal"?

Tags: folder

I accidentally removed Documents from Personal.

[image: a busy cat]

I went to Home directory, and Documents is not showing there anymore. I can't access it from Terminal either.

Trash doesn't contain it either.

Can I add it back again?

Comment: I had the same issue with trashcan but could not bring with its icon
and could not find exact location of it as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can navigate to your "Documents" folder then right click it. Select "add to bookmarks" or something similar.

Edit: Here you go

- Open up your File Manager
- Go to "Home"
- Right click on "Documents"
- Select "Bookmark"

"Documents" Should now be under "Personal" alongside your other bookmarks on the left.

Answer (score 1):

Try going to your home directory then dragging and dropping it into the list?

Comment: It's not showing in home directory. It's not showing anywhere. I cannot access it. Not even from Terminal.

Comment: Btw, dragging directories and dropping them does not work. SouperSoup's  answer was correct in that way. I don't know why you have the upvotes, and not him. :)

Comment: Good to hear you got it fixed. Go ahead and mark SouperSoup's response as the answer please :)